# find a substring with regex

Tags: regex

I'm trying to find how to match regex for the following string
"Myanmar | Yangon-Taunggyi | Search | Worldwide | EN"

I need to extract "Yangon-Taunggyi" so my question is how can I find with regex "Myanmar |" and "| Search | Worldwide | EN"

in general i need the second text between the |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?<=Myanmar\s\|\s).*(?=\s\|\sSearch)
```

this pattern will do the job, but if you can provide more examples, maybe i can generalize it.

You can see how this works [here](https://regex101.com/r/9lUBjk/1/)

**note: if don't works , dont downvote, ask before, i want to reach lvl to comment **

Comment: How can i do it more generic? meaning, the text before and after can change so basically i need the second element between the |

Comment: Then most likely you want `^[^|]+\|([^|]+)\s\|` .